# how to get data from object _field in firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

i need to get data from object (named "0") in a document in firestore, is that possible ?[image]
this is my code now:

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val docRef = db.collection("accessories")
            .document("brand0")
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot> { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val document = task.result
            val group = document.get("0") as ArrayList<String>
        }
```

but casting Any to Arraylist is not possible, any other way to get these data ?
[image]

Comment: Have you solve this issue? What did you do?

Comment: lol, this question was before three years when i was newbie in programming. I don't really remember how i solve it but I think casting solve it. `val group=document. get("0") as Map<String, String> ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `0` is a an object type field.  That means it'll be represented locally as a Map type object with strings as the keys for the properties it contains.

Comment: map like this: hashmap(key:String, Value :Any) yes I'm getting it like this, but here the Key will be "0" and the Value is the content of "0", so the value type is Any, i can't make use of it. i need the content of "0" as list or array.

Comment: I don't really understand. Can you edit your question to state what your final result is supposed to be, given the data in your doc?

Comment: i added new photo please take a look @Doug Stevenson

Comment: I still don't understand what's wrong with using the returned Map to get all the properties and values.

Comment: how to do that? i still can't figure out how to do that

Comment: Iterate the keys and values of the map with [`Map.forEach()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map#forEach(java.util.function.BiConsumer%3C?%20super%20K,%20?%20super%20V%3E)) or whatever method you prefer.

Comment: i will try my best in this comment to explain what's wrong with using the returned map. i need the "des" from "0", the returned map has key and value. the key here is "0" and the Value (supposed to be the strings inside "0") the value type is Any,  how can i get "des" from "0" when i got "0" as Any, i can't reach "des" or "id" or "trans" or anything inside "0", i wish i made it clear now. if i didn't so please forgive me and thank very much for your time

Comment: You can cast `group` to the expected type of Map and use it like you would any other Map.  `group.get("des")` should return you "testing".

Comment: i was trying to cast it to arraylist or list or array string and i couldn't. following your instruction to cast it to map i made the code like this: val group=document. get("0") as Map<String, String> ; val des = group.get("des")

Answer (score 0):

After some trials and errors this is what worked for me in the end, but I am not sure why. I am using kotlin in my current project.

```
fun getOwner(userId: String) {

    val db = Firebase.firestore

    val docRef = db.collection("users").document(userId)
    docRef.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            if (document != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")

                val data = document.data as Map<String, String>

                showOwnerName.text = data["name"]
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
        }

}
```

I am converting the data I am getting to a map and this is how I am able to access its values.